# Jenkins Publish Over SSH Returns a Null Error Message

Tags: jenkins, ssh

We're running into an error, but there are no logs or error message to help with the toubleshooting:

```
SSH: Connecting from host [xxxxxxxx]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [test_p805] ...
SSH: Creating session: username [p805s1], hostname [xxxxxxxx], port [22]
SSH: Connecting session ...
SSH: Connected
SSH: Opening SFTP channel ...
SSH: SFTP channel open
SSH: Connecting SFTP channel ...
SSH: Connected
SSH: cd [/]
SSH: OK
SSH: cd [/]
SSH: OK
SSH: cd [correct/destination/path]
SSH: OK
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [test_p805] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [null]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
```

We have a number of successful jobs working with this same configuration (test_p805). For this particular step, the configuration looks like this:

```
          <jenkins.plugins.publish__over__ssh.BapSshTransfer>
            <remoteDirectory>/correct/destination/path</remoteDirectory>
            <sourceFiles>${source_files}</sourceFiles>
            <excludes></excludes>
            <removePrefix></removePrefix>
            <remoteDirectorySDF>false</remoteDirectorySDF>
            <flatten>true</flatten>
            <cleanRemote>true</cleanRemote>
            <noDefaultExcludes>false</noDefaultExcludes>
            <makeEmptyDirs>false</makeEmptyDirs>
            <patternSeparator>[, ]+</patternSeparator>
            <execCommand></execCommand>
            <execTimeout>600000</execTimeout>
            <usePty>false</usePty>
          </jenkins.plugins.publish__over__ssh.BapSshTransfer>
```

where ${source_files} is a pattern that should pick up a jar file: `target\scala-2.10\*.jar`, and I've confirmed that a jar is in that location in the workspace.

Anyone run into this before?